# Не коннектится к БД PostgreSQL в IntelliJ IDEA Community

Tags: java, postgresql, pgadmin4, connection

Ошибка в подключении к базе данных, сама ошибка звучит как

**No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/windowapp**.

Заранее пролистал вопросы других, но они решались или загрузкой драйвера в папку lib MySQL, либо удалением текущих сеансов в pgadmin 4, либо нахождением опечатки в URL. Но я не использую MySQL, удалил все сеансы, проверил возможность опечатки, переустановил PostgreSQL, и даже перезагружал компьютер. Какой шаг или действие я пропустил?

Как всё происходило:

1. Скачал актуальную версию PostgreSQL 14(совместно с pgadmin 4 и прочими дополнениями)
2. В pgadmin 4 создал базу данных windowapp, использовал порт 5432 по дефолту
3. Создал самое обычное Java приложение в IntelliJ IDEA Community (без мавенов, гредлов, архетипов и т.д.)
4. Скачал плагин DB Browser для подключения к БД (другого плагина не отображало, параметра DataBase в пути View->Tool Window не было). В интернете не нашёл альтернативы.
5. В этом пункте прикреплю настройки БД:

[image]

> Здесь мы видим, что подключение происходит успешно

[image]

> Здесь показаны параметры (драйвера, их версия и т.д.) текущего подключения

6. Для проверки подключения сделал SQL запрос на добавление и заполнение таблиц через Console SQL в самой Idea, скрин не буду прилагать, в pgadmin всё прошло успешно, они там отобразились в нужной мне БД в указанном месте - **(PostgreSQL 14->Database->windowapp->Schemas->public->Tables)**.
7. В главном классе `main` пишу такой код <sub><sup>(естественно, обернул его в try/catch, но это тут не главное)</sup></sub>:

```java
            System.out.println("Сейчас будем коннектиться..");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD); // ругается именно на эту фразу DriverManager.getConnection
```

7.1 где **DB_URL** = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/windowapp"

7.2 **DB_USERNAME** = "postgres";

8. Ну и под конец, скрин ошибки:
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответом на мой вопрос было следующее:

1. Нажать на кнопку настройки проекта
2. Выбрать "Project Structure"
3. Далее в интерфейсе открывшегося окна выбрать "Moduls" добавить необходимый драйвер нажав "+".

P.S. Я только изучаю, поэтому не знал как правильно всё подключается (потратил 2 дня на сёрф в интернете, ничего не нашёл).

Мораль: пользуйтесь не только одним поисковиком